# Vandermonde's Convolution special case.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am not able to show this case of Vandermonde's Convolution without using induction. Can someone help me?

$$ \binom{n}{m} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-p}{m-k} \binom{p}{k}. $$

I thank now.

Comment: you can search in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients it is answered somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It   is convenient  to use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. We   can write    this way
\begin{align*}
[z^m](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{m}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{m}&\binom{n-p}{m-k}\binom{p}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[z^{m-k}](1+z)^{n-p}[u^k](1+u)^p\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^m](1+z)^{n-p}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k[u^k](1+u)^p\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^m](1+z)^{n-p}(1+z)^p\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^m](1+z)^n\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we introduce the coefficient of operator twice. We also set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything, since we add only zeros.
- In (3) we apply the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{m-k}]A(z)=[z^m]z^kA(z)
  \end{align*}
  rearrange and factor out terms which are not dependent on the index variable $k$
- In (4) we use the *substitution rule*
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k[t^k]A(t)\\
  \end{align*}