# Sum involving to combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to calculate the following sum:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\min\left\{M,n\right\}} \binom{N-M}{n-m}\binom{M}{m}.$$

> Attempt: The above sum is a part of a bigger problem.  By rearranging the bigger problem, I found that instead of above sum I need to find an ``alternative'' sum which is 
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^{\min\left\{M,n\right\}} \binom{N-n}{M-m}\binom{n}{m}.$$
>   I also found that such sums may be related to Gamma function, but I could not apply it here.

Comment: Suggesting to **close as duplicate** of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766053/vandermondes-convolution-special-case , even though the limits of your sums are slightly different (the difference is small: your $m=\operatorname{min}\left\{M, n\right\}$ upper bound is as good as any other upper bound, because above that bound the addends are all $0$ anyway; your $m=1$ lower bound differs from the usual $m=0$ lower bound just in one fewer addend). The keyword here is "Vandermonde convolution".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Suppose there are $N$ people, $M$ of which are women and the remaining $N-M$ of which are men.  Count how many ways there are to select $n$ of them such that there is at least one woman:

- Directly

or

- Indirectly by breaking into case based on the number of women selected

---

If we do it indirectly, we get the expression you wrote in your question, $\sum\limits_{m=1}^n \binom{N-M}{n-m}\binom{M}{m}$  (*note, the min in the limits doesn't actually matter*)

If we do it directly, you get a much simpler expression.  I'll leave it to you to find that expression.  The analogy of men and women and selecting $n$ of them should make it clear how to proceed.  By the nature that these expressions both correctly count the same scenario, they must be equal despite appearing differently.

> Count how many ways you can choose $n$ people from the $N$ available and remove those ways that contained only men.